# Why does this cmd operation not work?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm running this:

```
runas /profile /user:administrator "netsh interface set interface ""Ethernet 3"" admin=disabled"
```

It asks for password. After entering that in it doesnt do anything. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I've already set administrator active by doing

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

I'm running windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `runas /?` you'll see the way to quote quotes in the command string is `\"` not VB's `""`.

```
runas /profile /user:administrator "netsh interface set interface \"Ethernet 3\" admin=disabled"
```